# python matplotlib scatter coloring

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have a function that maps the unit square $[0,1]^2$ to either 0 or 1. How can I use matplotlib to illustrate the areas in the unit square on which the function takes 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous methods to graph values in two dimensions in matplotlib. [The documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) gives an overview:

[image]

Examples of the use of each method can also be found in the documentation. The decision, which method to choose is nothing we can help you with.